# How to keep html form data after submission using django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I created a form in `html` that returns data to `Django` each time it is submitted. However, when the page is reloaded after submission, the data entered in the form is lost. In order to solve this problem, I took inspiration from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/topics/forms/) and this [blog](https://moonbooks.org/Articles/Formulaire-conserver-les-donn%C3%A9es-apr%C3%A8s-soumission-avec-Django/) and then I modified my `views.py` file:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = request.POST['search']
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        max_pages_to_scrap = 15
        final_result = []
        for page_num in range(1, max_pages_to_scrap+1):
            url = "https://www.ask.com/web?q=" + search + "&qo=pagination&page=" + str(page_num)
            res = requests.get(url)
            soup = bs(res.text, 'lxml')
            result_listings = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'PartialSearchResults-item'})

            for result in result_listings:
                result_title = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-title').text
                result_url = result.find('a').get('href')
                result_desc = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-abstract').text
           
                final_result.append((result_title, result_url, result_desc))

        context = {'final_result': final_result}
        form = MyForm()

        return render(request, 'index.html', context,{'form':form})
```

I wrote the following code in my `models.py` file:

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models 

# Create your models here.

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
```

here is the content of my `index.html` file:

```
<form method="POST" action="search">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input  type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search here..." value="{{form.search.value}}" autofocus x-webkit-speech/>
                       
                </form>
```

Despite my modifications, the form data is not kept after submission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be saved, because you are passing brand new form to context:

```
...
form = MyForm()

return render(request, 'index.html', context,{'form':form})
```

Just move `form = MyForm()` to something like `elif request.method == 'GET':`:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    ...
    for page_num in range(1, max_pages_to_scrap+1):
        ...

elif request.method == 'GET':
    form = MyForm()

context = {'final_result': final_result, 'form': form}

return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

PS Keep `form` with your context, it's way clearer.

Comment: I would still like to know how to make the cursor end up at the end of the words entered in the form and not at the beginning because after the modification, each time I submit the data is certainly kept, but the cursor which was in final position is found in initial position in the form after page reload.

Comment: For that you need some javascript or htmx, so the post can be processed and rerendered without page reload. Check out: https://htmx.org/ - it's very useful for dynamic searches and stuff.

Comment: NixonSparrow thanks again for the answer to the question. In order to position the cursor at the end of the entered text, I used javascript, but despite this I can't control the position of the cursor. Here is my [stackoverflow] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72940576/how-to-modify-the-position-of-a-cursor-after-submitting-a-form-in-javascript) question. I would be very happy if you could help me because I've been stuck for days, thank you!