# How to modify the position of a cursor after submitting a form in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I've created a text input form in `html` that sends user input words via `POST` method to Django `views.py` file. Here is the code for this form

```html
<form method="POST" action="search">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input  type="search" name="search" value="{{form.search.value}}" placeholder="Search here..."  autofocus x-webkit-speech/>
                </form>
```

The `value` attribute takes the value returned by `Django` after a submit. Here is the code of my Django `views.py` file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


from search.models import MyForm



def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = request.POST['search']
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        
        max_pages_to_scrap = 15
        final_result = []
        for page_num in range(1, max_pages_to_scrap+1):
            url = "https://www.ask.com/web?q=" + search + "&qo=pagination&page=" + str(page_num)
            res = requests.get(url)
            soup = bs(res.text, 'lxml')
            result_listings = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'PartialSearchResults-item'})

            for result in result_listings:
                result_title = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-title').text
                result_url = result.find('a').get('href')
                result_desc = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-abstract').text
           
                final_result.append((result_title, result_url, result_desc))

        context = {'final_result': final_result, 'form':form}
        

        return render(request, 'index.html', context)

    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

When I submit the form, the value of the input field is well preserved but the cursor goes from the final position to the initial position. To solve this problem, I inserted a `javascript` script in my `index.html` file which contains my form:

```
 
    <script>
  
        /* Creating a function called PosEnd
         in JavaScript to place the cursor 
         at the end */
        function PosEnd(end) {
            var len = end.value.length;
              
            // Mostly for Web Browsers
            if (end.setSelectionRange) {
                end.focus();
                end.setSelectionRange(len, len);
            } else if (end.createTextRange) {
                var t = end.createTextRange();
                t.collapse(true);
                t.moveEnd('character', len);
                t.moveStart('character', len);
                t.select();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

and I modified the form like this:

```
<input  type="search" name="search" value="{{form.search.value}}" placeholder="Search here..."  autofocus x-webkit-speech/>
```

became:

```
<input  type="search" name="search" PosEnd(value="{{form.search.value}}") placeholder="Search here..."  autofocus x-webkit-speech/>
```

but now when I submit the form the input values ​​are lost. I look forward to your responses, thank you.